# RTC DS3231 inside a ESP32 task cause ESP restart while reading temperature

Tags: c++, c, task, esp32, freertos

I am creating a task associated with a ticker and a trigger. Everything is working fine. Within the task I read some sensors:

- Temperature/humidity of a DHT11
- Reading an MQ-2 gas sensor
- Reading a water sensor that I don't remember the model

Everything works as expected. However, when I try to read the temperature of an RTC DS3231 the ESP32 restarts. Outside the task, in the loop or setup the reading takes place perfectly.

I've tried everything I could, but I can't find the error I'm making. Could someone check my code?

```
bool CONFIG_TASK_SEGURANCA(){
    if (xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(SEGURANCA_Task, "SEGURANCA_Task", 4096, NULL, 0, &seguranca_TaskHandle, 0) != pdTRUE)
        return false;
    
    seguranca_Ticker.attach(seguranca_intervaloLeituraTASK, SEGURANCA_triggerTask); 
    return true;
}

void SEGURANCA_triggerTask(){
    if (seguranca_TaskHandle != NULL)
            xTaskResumeFromISR(seguranca_TaskHandle);       
}

void SEGURANCA_Task(void* pvParameters){
    while (1){
        if (seguranca_tasksEnabled)     
            SEGURANCA_AtualizarDados();
                
        vTaskSuspend(NULL);
    }
}

bool SEGURANCA_AtualizarDados()
{
    // --------------- DHT11

    if (DHT11_habilitado)
    {
        TempAndHumidity newValues = DHT11.getTempAndHumidity();

        if (DHT11.getStatus() != 0)
            return false;

        DHT11_Humidade = newValues.humidity;
        DHT11_Temperatura = newValues.temperature;
        DHT11_IndiceCalor = DHT11.computeHeatIndex(newValues.temperature, newValues.humidity);
        DHT11_PontoOrvalho = DHT11.computeDewPoint(newValues.temperature, newValues.humidity);

        String comfortStatus;
        switch (cf) {
        case Comfort_OK:
            DHT11_comfortStatus = F("AGRADAVEL");
            break;
        case Comfort_TooHot:
            DHT11_comfortStatus = F("MUITO QUENTE");
            break;
        case Comfort_TooCold:
            DHT11_comfortStatus = F("MUITO FRIO");
            break;
        case Comfort_TooDry:
            DHT11_comfortStatus = F("MUITO SECO");
            break;
        case Comfort_TooHumid:
            DHT11_comfortStatus = F("MUITO HUMIDO");
            break;
        case Comfort_HotAndHumid:
            DHT11_comfortStatus = F("QUENTE E HUMIDO");
            break;
        case Comfort_HotAndDry:
            DHT11_comfortStatus = F("QUENTE E SECO");
            break;
        case Comfort_ColdAndHumid:
            DHT11_comfortStatus = F("FRIO E HUMIDO");
            break;
        case Comfort_ColdAndDry:
            DHT11_comfortStatus = F("FRIO E SECO");
            break;
        default:
            DHT11_comfortStatus = F("INDETERMINADO");
            break;
        };
    }

    // --------------- MQ2

    if (MQ2_habilitado)
    {
        if (gpio_get_level(PIN_MQ2_IDF) == 0)
            MQ2_TEMfumo = 1;
        else
            MQ2_TEMfumo = 0;
    }

    // --------------- SENSOR DE AGUA

    if (sAgua_habilitado)
    {
        if (gpio_get_level(PIN_sAGUA_IDF) == 0)
            sAgua_TEMvazamento = 1;
        else
            sAgua_TEMvazamento = 0;
    }

    // --------------- TEMPERATURA DO SISTEMA (DS3231)

    /*
    *** CAUSE ESP RESTART
    RtcTemperature temperatura;
    temperatura = RTC_DS3231.GetTemperature();
    float aaa = temperatura.AsFloatDegC();
    */

    /*
    *** CAUSE ESP RESTART
    RtcTemperature temperatura;
    temperatura = RTC_DS3231.GetTemperature().AsFloatDegC();
    float aaa = temperatura.AsFloatDegC();
    */

    /*
    *** CAUSE ESP RESTART
    RtcTemperature temperatura;
    temperaturaDS3231 = RTC_DS3231.GetTemperature().AsFloatDegC();
    char buf[6];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%01d", temperaturaDS3231);
    */

    /*
    *** CAUSE ESP RESTART
    int RTC_DS3231_temperatura;
    RtcTemperature temperatura;
    temperatura = RTC_DS3231.GetTemperature().AsFloatDegC();

    char buf[3];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%01d", temperaturaDS3231);
    sscanf(buf, "%d", &RTC_DS3231_temperatura);
    */

    return true;
}
```

Comment: 'char buf[3];'......anything that small worries me.......

Comment: What message does the ESP output when it restarts?

Comment: the only information that is not in hexa is divisionbyzero.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any division operations in the code that you've commented out. How about sharing the crash dump from ESP?

Comment: This line cause restart:
RtcTemperature tempDS3231 = RTC_DS3231.GetTemperature().AsFloatDegC();

-----------// --------

Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IntegerDivideByZero). Exception was unhandled.
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x400e4d45  PS      : 0x00060930  A0      : 0x800e5126  A1      : 0x3ffb1d50  
A2      : 0x00000133  A3      : 0x00000000  A4      : 0x00000032  A5      : 0x3ffbec18  
A6      : 0x00004e20  A7      : 0x60013000  A8      : 0x00000113  A9      : 0x3ffb1d30  
-----------// --------

 and more Hexa code